# Pair production problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pair-production

Can you explain me why in the pair production process we need a minimum energy $E_\gamma=2m_e$ in terms of invariant mass?

I tried to calculate it but I get another result like $E_\gamma=2m_e+\frac{2m_e^2}{m_N}$ where $N$ is the nucleus.

Comment: It would help if you write down a summary of how did you get that expression

Comment: Why is what you obtained incompatible with $2m_e$ being the minimum?

Comment: $s_i=2p_\gamma m_N+m_N^2$ and $s_f=m_N^2+4m_N m_e+4m_e^2$ so that $p_\gamma=2m_e+\frac{2m_e^2}{m_N}$